# How to properly use require.js to require a node module?

Tags: node.js, module, requirejs, require

So, I have no experience with Node or require.js. I know questions similar to this one have already been posted, but unfortunately, their solutions were no use in my case, sorry.

So all I'm trying to achieve here is to use the [random-words](https://github.com/punkave/random-words) Node module in my app (client-side). After I have installed it with `npm install random-words`, I am trying to use this:

```
var randomWords = require('random-words');  
console.log(randomWords());
```

but with no luck. I have been trying to get this to work for over 2 hours now, reading the documentation, watching tutorials, searching on Stack Overflow but I always get an error. Right now, I am getting this output/errors:

```
Require inside of index.html executed

    Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at index.js:338
    (anonymous) @ index.js:338

    require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Module name "node_modules/random-words" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
    https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
        at makeError (require.js:5)
        at Object.s [as require] (require.js:5)
        at requirejs (require.js:5)
        at script.js:2
        at Object.execCb (require.js:5)
        at e.check (require.js:5)
        at e.<anonymous> (require.js:5)
        at require.js:5
        at require.js:5
        at each (require.js:5)
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
My App
|-- js
|   |-- script.js
|   `-- node_modules
|       `-- random-words
|           |-- tests
|           |   `-- test.js
|           |-- index.js
|           `-- package.json
|-- config.js
|-- index.html
|-- package-lock.json
`-- require.js
```

My code inside index.html:

```
<script data-main='config' src='require.js'></script>
    <script>
    require(['config'], function(){
        require(['script']);
        console.log("Require inside of index.html executed");
    });
    </script>
```

My code inside config.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        randomWords: 'node_modules/random-words/index'
    }
});
```

My code inside script.js:

```
define(['randomWords'], function(){
                var randomWords = require('node_modules/random-words');
                console.log("Script.js code executed");
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any response/advice, I am getting really desperate and will not be able to move on until I get this to work.

Comment: Is this a node.js question or a browser question?  Where are you trying to use the random-words module?

Comment: On client side, hence the use of require.js

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem, and found the answer [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) under the "Common Errors" section of requirejs.org:

> This occurs when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not been loaded yet.
> If the error message includes Use require([]), then it was a top-level require call (not a require call inside a define() call) that should be using the async, callback version of require to load the code

So instead of:

```
var randomWords = require('random-words');  
console.log(randomWords());
```

using:

```
var randomWords = require(['random-words'], function (random) {
    });
console.log(randomWords());
```

fixed the issue for me.